# Power factor help!

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

[image]

I need to answer the following based on the diagram, but I just don't understand the power factor triangle (given I haven't completed any sort of study like this for over 15 years!).

I have worked out

- V1 is 360 V.
- I2 is 45 A.
- I1 is 900 A.

Hoping the above answers are correct. Which formulas can I use to answer the questions and have this make more sense to me?

Comment: You need to start at the beginning and learn the basics of ac circuits. The only thing you have right is V1.

Comment: No, V1 is wrong - it is stated as 7.2 kV.

Comment: What you have marked as V1 is actually V2. I assumed you knew that but mistyped it. I should have said that, but the part of my brain that should have told be to say that fell asleep on the job.

Comment: sorry guys - total typo. my answers so far are as follows: voltage of v2 = 360v - the current of I2 = 45amp the true power is 16200w and the current I1 = 900amp. how am i going so far? I just dont get the power triangle. Iv studied, its one thing that i cant get to stick! I get a bit lost with the cos part.

Answer (score 0):

You should review a resource like the ac section of allaboutcircuits.com
There you will see how to sum complex impedance, and work with transformers.

Transformer Hint: 
$$\frac{N_1}{N_2}=\frac{V_1}{V_2}=\frac{I_2}{I_1}=\sqrt{\frac{Z_P}{Z_L}}$$

You need to find \$V_2\$ to carry on, then you can use the information in the secondary circuit to find the current \$I_2\$. Use the transformer equations to relate this result to \$I_1\$. The impedance of the secondary circuit can be referred to the primary by the transformer equations. But go and read up on the resource I mentioned before proceeding...https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, \$ V_2 \$ = 360V.

You have to work out impedance Z of load.

You have ignored the inductance \$ X_L \$ = j = 7\$\Omega\$ (assuming unit is Ohms).  You just used the 8\$\Omega\$ resistor, so \$ I_2 \ne 45A \$, which makes \$ I_1 \$ wrong, too.

The order of the questions lead you to the answers.

[image: power triangle]

The power triangle looks like this.

Average or Real Power \$P = I_2^2 R \$ in W.

Reactive Power \$Q_L = I_2^2 X_L \$ in VAR.

Apparent Power, which your question calls Effective Power \$S = I_2^2 Z \$ in VA.

Power factor \$ pf = \frac {P}{S} =  cos\ \theta\$.

This should give you the answers, but time to hit the books.  Use this, edit your question and I'll confirm your answers.

Comment: TBH i didnt realise the j=7 WAS the inductance! to get the I2 i did the following formula: V=IR workings: 360= i2 x 8 therefore  - 360/8 = 45amp - have i totally confused myself and the formula?

Comment: Yes.  Z = R + j X.  Order of question quides you to the answer.  R is not the total opposition.